# Estimating the size of $\|\nabla s\|_{L^2}$ locally

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the following estimate from a book of John Roe. The setting is as follows. Suppose $\nabla$ is a connection on a vector bundle $S$ over a closed manifold $M$. We want to make a local estimate of the $L^2$-norm

$$\|\nabla s\|_0^2$$

of $\nabla s\in C^\infty(T^*M\otimes S)$. Here the notation $\|\cdot\|_k$ means the $k$-th Sobolev norm, defined locally as

$$\|f\|_k=\sum_{i=0}^k\|\frac{\partial^\alpha f}{\partial x^\alpha}\|_0,$$

for a section $f$ of $S$ supported over the local coordinate chart. The $0$-th Sobolev space is identified with $L^2(S)$.

The author writes:

[image]

Now I understand the equality, but not the next inequality. In particular, why does there exist a positive constant $C_2$ for which this is true? It seems to me that when $i\neq j$, the term $\displaystyle\int g^{ij}(\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^j})$ could be negative and large. How can we estimate the size of this term?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the notation right. But to me it seems like $g^{ij}(\partial s/\partial x^i, \partial s /\partial x^j)$ is essentially a "norm squared" of $\partial s$. So it is exactly equal to $\|{s}\|_{1}^2$. (Since this is a partial derivative and not a covariant derivative, this is off by a term like $\Gamma \cdot s$ which appears and is controlled in the next term.)

Comment: I might not be interpreting the notation correctly either, but like if the coordinates were $x_1,x_2$, then there could be a term like $g^{12}(\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^1},\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^2})\neq 0$, which does not appear in the formula for $\|s\|_1=\|s\|_0+\|\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^1}\|_0+\|\frac{\partial s}{\partial x_2}\|_0$?